# How can I solve the conditional probability question in a dataset in python?

Tags: python, probability

```
df

Size gender  drink_water
    12    0        10
    15    1        15
    18    1        12
    8     0        8
    6     1        11
    .     .         .
```

Hello. I have a hypothetical data set,I have no other information. I want to know the probability of a dog of size 11 and gender 1 drinking less than 10 liters of water per month(I don't have these values in dataset). What can I do?

Average drink water per dog is 0.08.

Answer (score 1):

> I am assuming you want P('size' =11, 'gender' = 1, 'drink_waters' <10).

You sum the number of rows with  columns 'gender' == 1 & 'size' == 11 & 'drink_waters' <10. Then you divide that sum by the length of your dataset(#rows) and you're done.

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if I could solve it with a probability distribution function like binomial, poisson etc.

Comment: In this case is just as simple as I wrote above, but in general if all the three features had a known distribution yes you should be able to play with the formulas and compute, given the parameters, the probability of this 3 events together.